# Darknet model to onnx

Tags: darknet, tensorrt, onnx

I am currently working with Darknet on Yolov4, with 1 class.

I need to export those weights to onnx format, for tensorRT inference.
I've tried multiple technics, using [ultralytics](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov3) to convert or [going from tensorflow to onnx](https://github.com/hunglc007/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite). But none seems to work. Is there a direct way to do it?

Answer (score 5):

Check this GitHub repo: https://github.com/Tianxiaomo/pytorch-YOLOv4

Running the `demo_darknet2onnx.py` script you'll be able to generate the ONNX model from the `.cfg` and `.weights` darknet files.

Usage example:

`python demo_darknet2onnx.py <cfgFile> <weightFile> <imageFile> <batchSize>`

You can also decide the batch size for the inference calls of the converted model.

Answer (score 2):

The following repo exports yolov3 models from darknet to onnx, for tensorRT inference. You can use this as reference for your model.

https://github.com/jkjung-avt/tensorrt_demos/tree/master/yolo

Comment: This link is no longer available

Comment: I think it was renamed?  Is it this?  https://github.com/jkjung-avt/tensorrt_demos/tree/master/yolo